# LED driver on 74HC164 - need explanation

Tags: shift-register

I'm building thermometer with long led bargraph (is that correct word?). It will be 60x 0805 LEDs. I want to use low-cost PIC16F1503 microcontroller with just 12 I/O pins.

I have few spare 74HC164 shift registers, so I decided to use them in this project. I was looking for some ideas and I found this 7-segment LED driver:

[image]

[Original image link](http://cache.amobbs.com/bbs_upload782111/files_13/ourdev_433633.jpg)

Unfortunately [page with description](http://www.amobbs.com/thread-3278926-1-1.html) is in chinese or japanese.

**Can someone explain how it works in general?**

I don't understand why next shift register is connected to last output of previous register.

Comment: Suggest using 74HC595 parts which have a built-in latch- that way you won't have 'ghosting'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shift register like the one you mentioned will take 8 bits sequentially (one at a time) and output them in parallel on its 8 outputs. You can chain two of these together by linking the last bit of the first register to the serial input of the next. What you get then is the equivalent of a 16 bit shift register. You can go on chaining several registers like this, each adding 8 bits to the setup.

What makes this possible is that, when you input the 9th bit on the 1st shift register, the very first bit entered (that is now on the 8th position) gets pushed into the next shift register and so on.

In the image you've shown, there are 8 shift registers linked in chain, which let's you input 64 bits and control 8 7-segments displays without the need to multiplex the segments.

Below is an animation of how one shift register works (thanks to [totymedli](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/87/totymedli) for the great animated gif). The image was originally posted on [this answer](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/139/46) at [Arduino StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

[image: Shift register animation]

In the animation above, the red dot on the upper-left corner is the shift register serial input. Every time the clock (small green dot pulsating near the lower-left corner) goes up, the shift register will insert the input into the first bit, and push all the other bits one position to the right. The 8th bit is pushed out of the shift register into its overflow bit (not shown in the animation). Imagine now that this overflow bit is fed into a 2nd shift register serial input. That will allow you to feed other 8 bits into the chain.

I know it's not your case, but there's more information on how to drive a similar shift register (LS74HC595) with Arduinos on [this answer of mine](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/119/46).

Here are a few links I found googling about controlling your shift register with PIC:

- [Interfacing 74HC164 with PIC](http://www.edaboard.com/thread294335.html)
- [How to use 74Hc164 for drive 7segment?](http://www.protonbasic.co.uk/showthread.php/54537-How-to-use-74Hc164-for-drive-7segment)

Comment: But it won't trigger if 8-th bit (MSb) is low...

Comment: Ah, now I see. If 8-th bit is low there is no need to push it to next register.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying in the comments above, but it seems like you're confusing clock with the serial input. The same clock signal is shared between all shift registers. So you put HIGH or LOW on the serial input, and make clock transition from LOW to HIGH. That pushes all the bits on all registers one position to the right.

Answer (score 1):

There is a potentially better way - actually two ways. Let me start by pointing out that, in order to reduce the number of ON LEDs, you will have to shift an entire new pattern into your display, and this will produce a certain amount of ghosting.

Alternative 1 - Instead of a data and a clock line, tie the shift register input high, and drive a clock line and a reset line. Then, when you want to load new data, reset all the shift registers and then shift the appropriate number of clock pulses. This will produce a slight flicker in the ON part of the bar graph, but this will generally be better that a ghost illumination of the OFF part.

Alternative 2 - Replace the HC164's with HC194's. Tie the left input high, and the right input low. Now provide a clock and a direction line. At power-on, shift left 60 times to set all the outputs to OFF. Then, shift right the proper number of times to display the bar size you want. From then on, if you want to increase the length of the ON section, just shift right as many times as necessary. To decrease the ON length, shift left. This will change the ON length as necessary without any flicker or ghost.